# Entered text on form field appears on image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, forms

Tried googling for this in many different ways, but I havent been able to find a solution to this. Sorry for not having any code to work with in advance.

Here's what I am envisioning...

**Step 1:** User enters "Andrew" in a text field

**Step 2:** The text appears on an image at a certain position.

For example, the image is a picture of the words "My name is ***_*_**".
The words "Andrew" will appear in the blank space.

**Step 3:** User will be able to download the image as a .png

Comment: Why do you want it as an image? Surely text will be sufficient. But if you insist on having images you will have to get the server to create them on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using canvas html5 element. With it, you can load your existing image in canvas

```
canvas.drawImage(image, dx, dy)
```

Then you can draw text in the same font on a certain position. Here you can find more information about [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and a [tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#text) about using it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use imagemagick for image manipulations on the server side

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

In case you do not have root privileges on your server you could use php's image functions as well

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function move(params)
    {

   var txt = document.getElementById(params.id).value;
   alert(txt);
   var ele = document.getElementById("myimage");
   document.getElementById("myimage").innerHTML += txt;

   //set your corresponding position
   ele.style.position = 'absolute';
   ele.style.left     = 100+'px';
   ele.style.top      = 100+'px';
     }
     </script>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="itext"/>
  <input type="button" id="ibutton" text="move" value="move"   onclick="move({id:'itext'});"/>
   <div id="myimage">sss</div>
  </body>
    </html>
```